# Return one dimensional array from the query in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to get `in` part in one dimension as; `["art", "music", "cinema" , "calculus" , "science"]`

structure is;

```
enrolled:
[
    {in : "art", registerAt: ""},
    {in : "music", registerAt: ""},
    {in : "cinema", registerAt: ""},
    {in : "calculus", registerAt: ""},
    {in : "science", registerAt: ""},
]
```

to be able to do this I wrote a query;

```
db.deneme.find({}, {"enrolled.in"  : 1, _id: 0}).toArray(function(err, result){
  var arr =[];
  for(var i=0; i < result.in.length; i++){
    arr.push( result.in[i].in);
  }
})
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` query

```
db.deneme.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$enrolled"},
    {$group:{
        _id:"$_id",
        in:{$addToSet:"$enrolled.in"}
        }
    }
]).toArray(function(err, result){
  console.log(result)
})
```